# TexMaker: switch dictionary / language confortably

Tags: texmaker, languages

I'm writing documents in different languages and enjoy using the auto-correction (aka dictionary). I have to switch quite frequently (often I have documents in different languages opened at the same time). Unfortunately, it's quite deep in the settings and you have to search the correct file each time (by the way, why is there for each language a file like *en-UK.dic* and one like *en_UK.dic* ?). Consulting the man-page I could not even find a param for starting it using a defined dictionary.

Is there a quick possibility for switching languages?

By the way, I'm working on Ubuntu.

Comment: I recommend you to use TeXstudio. It is very similar and easy to change dicts. Just use the status bar.

Comment: ...and it has somewhat fewer bugs.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it. But the question remains.

Comment: Looks good - and very similar. Is one forked from the other? Great feature is, that you can add a comment in the document `% !TeX spellcheck = en_UK` or similar and it will switch automatically for you. Thanks!

Comment: @3244611user, it is a fork from TeXmaker. It is the older TeXmakerx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of version 4.4, TexMaker supports the `% !TeX spellcheck = [language code]` meta tag to specify the spellcheck language of the file. If you've already opened the file, close and re-open the file to trigger a rescan of the language.

I have successfully tested this feature with TexMaker 4.5. The default spellcheck language is English, but with the following tag it becomes Dutch:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = nl_NL
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
...
```

From ChangeLog (http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/log.html):

> - support for the meta tags "% !TEX encoding=" and "% !TEX spellcheck" has been added (the meta tag "% !TEX root" is already supported)